# SMIE default syntax : First level of indentation

Tags: indentation, major-mode, smie

When you only do that in your major mode :

```
(require 'smie)
(smie-setup nil #'ignore)
```

That means [SMIE](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html) but no [grammar](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE-Grammar.html#SMIE-Grammar), and no [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE-Indentation.html#SMIE-Indentation). And it's *great*. It makes the point stay on col0 when you `TAB` and there's nothing on the line, it makes indentation basically sane and logic for a c-like major mode derived from fundamental-mode.

Except for this weird detail : The first indentation level is messed up :

```
plop = {
    plop;
        plop;
        plop;
        plop;
}
```

Is that a bug? It looks like a bug. And if it's not, how can I make it so that :

```
plop = {
    plop;
    plop;
    plop;
    plop;
}
```